# PHP script doesn't import CSV into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv

```
# download the file off the internet
    $file = file_get_contents("http://localhost/sample.csv");
    $filepath = "C:/xampp/htdocs/test/file/sample.csv";
    file_put_contents($filepath, $file);
# load the data into sample table
    $pt1 = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ";
    $pt2 = "'/C:/xampp/htdocs/test/file/sample.csv' INTO TABLE sample ";
    $pt3 = "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' ";
    $pt4 = "LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' ";
    $pt5 = "(col1,col2,col3,col4)";
    $sqlquerynew = $pt1.$pt2.$pt3.$pt4.$pt5;
    mysql_query($sqlquerynew);
```

This piece of code works on non-csv (well, I tested it with a text file instead).

Before this part gets run, I have to create a table. The table is now created, but no data is loaded. The file stated in the path exists.

What could be the problem?

Thanks

This is a sample csv I found online

```
"REVIEW_DATE","AUTHOR","ISBN","DISCOUNTED_PRICE"
"1985/01/21","Douglas Adams",0345391802,5.95
"1990/01/12","Douglas Hofstadter",0465026567,9.95
       ....... etc
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? have you tried removing the headers line? or add `IGNORE 1 LINES` after `INTO TABLE sample`

Comment: @Yaniro Thanks. I don't have any error message displayed (on browser). Yes I did, it still doesn't work.

Comment: What happens if you do this from the command line? (i mean `mysql` command prompt)

Comment: This is a question: Did you create table in advance or are you expecting to create table on the fly through LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE?

Comment: @user1260310 There will be SQL query to create the tables before this part is ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems

```
$pt2 = "'/C:/xampp/htdocs/test/file/sample.csv' INTO TABLE sample ";
```

Remove the `/` in front of C.

and secondly,

```
$pt5 = "(col1,col2,col3,col4)";
```

Make sure you have the right name for the columns. If you want to import `*` all columns, just remove it. It is also a good idea to remove the header in your case, because removing `$pt5` you will succeed, but the header row will be added to the table.